# Get Google Backup and Sync to only sync one file at a time instead of three?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, online-backup

I have Google Backup and Sync set to upload all files in a folder to Google Drive. The default behavior seems to sync 3 files simultaneously. Is there any way to set it to sync only one file at a time?

Answer (score 1):

I am having this exact issue.
The files are 360 video files, about 4 GB each, and an hours recording can produce 6-10 of them. Backing up the videos can take DAYS...even if leaving the computer on overnight!

I suspect that if only a percentage of the file is backed up before I need to shut down, that is lost and the process starts over from scratch when the computer is turned on again.

I just hit on a potential workaround this morning.
Copy (or move) one file at a time into the synced folder, which forces Backup and Sync to work on only one file at a time.

Tedious? YES! 
But the files do eventually get completely saved in a reasonable amount of time as opposed to three files that only ever get to 15-20% because I needed to shut down and go to work.